# Bedeutung von "ich sage" in Reden

Tags: usage, meaning-in-context

Aus [Angela Merkels Rede am 9. November](http://www.bundesregierung.de/Content/DE/Rede/2014/11/2014-11-09-merkel-gedenkstaette-berliner-mauer.html):

> Ich wünsche der Ausstellung viele, vor allem auch junge Besucherinnen und Besucher. Ihnen fehlen natürlich die eigenen Erinnerungen an die Zeit der deutschen Teilung und an den 9. November 1989. Für sie ist der Mauerfall – **ich sage: glücklicherweise** – Geschichte.

Was meint sie mit "ich sage" hier? Ist es wie

> ich betone

oder

> es ist nur meine Meinung

?

Ist "ich sage" eine gewöhnliche Phrase in deutschen Reden?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Die Wendung „ich sage“ ist hier ein rhetorisches Stilmittel, um stark zu betonen und die eigene Meinung auszudrücken. Beide Bedeutungen, die Du nennst, treffen also zu. Auch drückt „ich sage“ aus, dass andere möglicherweise das anders sehen, und die Rednerin den Zuhörern nahelegt, dass sie und nicht diese anderen recht hat.

Comment: In einem Wort: *Beide* Vorschläge der Fragestellung sind richtig.

Comment: "und die Rednerin den Zuhörern nahelegt, dass sie und nicht diese anderen recht hat" - ich finde nicht, dass das in der Redewendung drinsteckt. Ich verstehe das "ich sage" eher als Abschwächung, um zu verdeutlichen, dass es sich bei der Bemerkung nicht um eine objektiv belegbare (wenn man sie direkt im Anschluss an die Rede fragen würde) Tatsache handelt, sondern eben "nur" um ihre persönliche Meinung.